# JQuery not running simple function of multiply values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a JQuery function, on which i am trying to simply apply the multiplication of 2 inputs onto a 3rd input.

But, for some reason, it isn't working.
What i basically want to do, is for the result to automatically appear on the 3rd input, after i have values on the first 2

I tried searching for an answer, but maibe due to inexperience, i am unable to use the correct keywords. Sorry for that

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".txtMult input").keyup(multInputs);

   function multInputs() {
       var mult = 0;
       // for each row:
       $("txtMult").each(function () {
           // get the values from this row:
           var $val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
           var $val2 = $('.val2', this).val();
           var $total = ($val1 * 1) * ($val2 * 1)
           $('.multTotal',this).text($total);
           mult += $total;
       });
    });


    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="txtMult">
    <div class="row">
        <label for="name">Comprimento em centimetros:</label><br />
        <input id="cmp" class="val1" name="cmp" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="email">Largura em centimetros:</label><br />
        <input id="lrg" class="val2" name="lrg" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="email">Área em M<small>2</small></label><br />
        <div class='section'>
        <input id="lrg" class="multTotal" name="lrg" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: all of your inputs have the same 'id', you miss a dot '.' on your $.each code... try to put together an example code at JsFiddle and it will be easier for us to help you...

Comment: Check [this](http://jsbin.com/OJOlARe/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @Nameismy I tried changing to what that Fiddle says, but it won't run.
Maibe i'm missing some point to make it run automatically? If so, i don't know what it is

Comment: Why negative vote? There must be some suggestion or guidance. I can't see any valid reason

Comment: @Sami I didn't understand eighter.. Got a negative vote for a "noob" question?
I tried searching around, and there's probably an answer somewhere already, as i know this is probably a common error to beginers, but, i explained that i searched as best as i can to my extent of english wording..

Comment: You are getting problem in elements selection. Do it simpler. I have tried to show in my answer. Also

Ids should be always unique. And you don't need to use each here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things:

- First you are not binding `each` to proper `selector` and you are missing `.` for `class selector`
- Second instead of assigning `.val` to `input type="text"` you are
  trying to assign `.text` which will not work.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/53r8nn8j/2/)**

Below are the changes you need to do:

```
$(".txtMult input").keyup(multInputs);
function multInputs() {
       var mult = 0;
       // for each row:
       $(".txtMult").each(function () {
           var $val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
           var $val2 = $('.val2', this).val();
           var $total = ($val1 * 1) * ($val2 * 1)
           $('.multTotal',this).val($total); //should be .val()
           mult += $total;
       });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing that for me. I understood what i had wrong in not assigning the classes.
But, it is still not working, even after correcting those parts of the code :(

Comment: I did check it, but it isn't running correctly on my end, when i apply it to my local website

Comment: @Heatmanofurioso then problem is with your end buddy!! You need to debug or check console for any errors!

Comment: I believe i may be missing something on the body to make it continuously working maibe? Not sure about that. Something similar to the onload method?
Tried debugging and checked console. All clear

Comment: place a `debugger` in your `javascript ` and check whether it is hitting your event or not!! may be you are having more elements since you are using `each` and that is causing the issue!! posting the whole code might help to resolve!

Comment: Placed a debugger on my javascript. Placed it both at beguinning and ending of each function. It always flashes up on the console. Also, no errors are being demonstrated.
Also, i place my code on a fiddle, and it works correctly there. 
The problem is clearly on my end somehow. I will search it up. But thanks, you answered my initial question and gave me a good support to my questions!

Comment: Anytime. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `.` as prefix for the class here

```
$(".txtMult").each(function () {
---^---
```

Edit:

Need to change from `.text()` to `.val()` as for inputs we set value using `val` only.

```
$('.multTotal', this).val($total);
```

[**`FIDDLE DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/9q7b2956/)

Answer (score 1):

here is a working [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ronency/vuojw795/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="txtMult">
    <div class="row">
        <label for="name">Comprimento em centimetros:</label><br />
        <input id="cmp" class="val1" name="cmp" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="email">Largura em centimetros:</label><br />
        <input id="lrg" class="val2" name="lrg" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="email">Área em M<small>2</small></label><br />
        <div class='section'>
        <input id="lrg" class="multTotal" name="lrg" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
 function multInputs() {
     $(".txtMult").each(function () {
         var $current = $(this);
         // get the values from this row:
         var val1 = $('.val1', $current).val();
         var val2 = $('.val2', $current).val();
         if (val1 != '' && val2 != '') {
             var total = parseInt(val1) * parseInt(val2);
             $('.multTotal', $current).val(total);
         }
     });
 };
```

$(".txtMult input").keyup(multInputs);

Comment: Although i hate "copy paste".
Even after doing so from your fiddle, and other fiddles, the code just isn't working.
I am running Xampp correctly, as other jscript is working fine. But not this, for some reason

Comment: Try to put a JsFiddle with your exact code, that actually reproduces the bug, and that way we can better help you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of errors in that code.
Here is a corrected version that works (I've added a few things, like parseInt and checking that the result isn't NaN):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="character-encoding" charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {

        function multInputs() {

            var mult = 0;
            // for each row:
            $(".txtMult").each(function () {
                // get the values from this row:
                var $val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
                var $val2 = $('.val2', this).val();
                var $total = parseInt($val1) * parseInt($val2);
                if (!isNaN($total)) {
                    $('.multTotal', this).val($total);
                }
                mult += $total;
            });
        }

        $(".txtMult input").keyup(multInputs);
    });


</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="txtMult">
    <div class="row">
        <label for="name">Comprimento em centimetros:</label><br />
        <input id="cmp" class="val1" name="cmp" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="email">Largura em centimetros:</label><br />
        <input id="lrg" class="val2" name="lrg" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="email">Área em M<small>2</small></label><br />
        <div class='section'>
            <input id="lrg" class="multTotal" name="lrg" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of elements selection. With Id `#`, class `.`, or position `eq(n)`

[Demo on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qMIb3bNOB42mywy5qDy3?p=preview)

```
function multInputs() {

 var val1 = $('#cmp').val();
 var val2 = $('#lrg').val();
 $('#result').val(val1*val2);

 //Or
 //var inputs = $(".txtMult input");
 //var val1 = inputs.eq(0).val();
 //var val2 = inputs.eq(1).val();
 //inputs.eq(2).val(val1*val2);

}
```